# sns plot: ValueError: Could not interpret input

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, valueerror

I have a flat file with 31 rows and around 50k columns.

1. import file and group to new data frame. The code below works and results is shown:

   ```
   RTE_subject = rte.groupby(by=["RTE Subject Type", "Account: External ID"]).agg({"Sent":"sum",                                                     "Opened":"sum",                                                                           "Clicked":"sum"})
   RTE_subject["cr"]=RTE_subject.Opened/RTE_subject.Sent
   RTE_subject["ctr"]=RTE_subject.Clicked/RTE_subject.Opened
   print(RTE_subject.head())
   ```

   results of the code:

   [image: results of the code]
2. I try to build box plot using `RTE_subject`:

   ```
   sns.catplot(data=RTE_subject,
               x="RTE Subject Type",
               y="ctr",
               kind="box")
   plt.show()
   ```

   but got this message `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'RTE Subject Type'`.

Comment: when you group by that column -- and another column -- those two will go into your index, becoming a MultiIndex. you can either specify `x=RTE_subject.index.get_level_values("RTE Subject Type")` or get that part of the MultiIndex back into the DataFrame's columns.

Comment: possibly `RTE_subject.reset_index()` -- to "flatten" the MultiIndex -- would be a better solution if you're doing anything else to that DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you index reset, has helped!